# How can I increase the number of posts my Squarespace site shows per page?

Tags: blogs, space, squarespace, square

The Squarespace editor limits the number of blog posts per page to 20. I would like to increase this limit, but I don't know how or where to do that.

Is this possible?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. You just have workarounds. Summaries have a 30 limit, instead of 20, then again, you can also "chain" them by putting up multiple summary blocks. This is the way most do it.

Then again, there's [this](https://www.squarewebsites.org/squarespace-plugins/lazy-summaries): "The lazy load summaries" plugin that has an option to go over the 30 item limit.

There's no "real" native way to do it other than with summary blocks or plugins (and even then, not for the actual posts). For now, anyway.

Comment: Hmm, that's disappointing. It is just because all of the limiting is done server-side?

Comment: I can't say 100%, but probably. It might be the traffic that's sent which is prolly limited to "what it needs to be" or some other limitation or even a design choice. As I said, the best course of action is to use lists of summary blocks or the paid plugin. While it's not quite the same thing, at least you'll have more than 20 items. If you consider the solutions are enough either upvote or mark it as accepted please, so that it can help others that are looking for what you did :)